# media queries for mobile optimisation

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I've added the following to my site to target phones/tabets etc:

```
<link href="assets/styles/phone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 640px)" >
<link href="assets/styles/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 768px)" >
<link href="assets/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 769px)" >
```

The stylesheets clearly work as they dynamically change within the browser, however the mobile devices I've tested are still targeting the main stylesheet, not the mobile versions.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: On what mobile devices did you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Devices use `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` try to add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 />`

to your header.

Hope this helps